# Third Moment of Expectation?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, expected-value, variance

I'm trying to find the $E[X^3]$ in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.
I found online somewhere that it's

$\mu^3 + 3\mu\sigma^2$.

But there's no proof or explanation *anywhere* for it. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 3):

For a general distribution, $\mu,\,\sigma^2$ doesn't determine $E[X^3]$.

For a Normal distribution, write $X=\mu+\sigma Z$ with $Z\sim N(0,\,1)$ so$$E[X^3]=E[(\mu+\sigma Z)^3]=E[\mu^3+3\mu^2\sigma Z+3\mu\sigma^2Z^2+\sigma^3Z^3]=\mu^3+3\mu\sigma^2.$$More generally, with $Z:=(X-\mu)/\sigma$ we call $\Bbb EZ^3$ the skewness of $X$, [and denote it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson's_moment_coefficient_of_skewness) $\tilde{\mu}_3$. Then $\Bbb EZ^3=\mu^3+3\mu\sigma^2+\sigma^3\tilde{\mu}_3$.

Comment: I'm unsure how to lose the E(Z^3), is it just zero because there isn't a parameter for it in the standard normal distribution?

Comment: @p-onyo As I said, it is a fact that the Normal distribution satisfies $\tilde{\mu}_3=0$, but this doesn't hold more generally. In fact, any symmetric distribution will have $\tilde{\mu}_3$ either $0$ or undefined.